# Trying to mock Environment.getExternalStorageState

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, environment

I've been trying to figure out for some hours how to mock the call to `Environment.getExternalStorateState()` while unit testing my Android App.

I've been able to mock SystemServices, Providers and Services, but I cannot work out how to mock this call, as it is not a call to something provided within my context, but something in the OS environment.

Would be grateful about some help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could write helper around this call and easily mock it after (sorry for having helper part in class name):

```
public class EnvironmentHelper {
    public String getStorageState() {
        return Environment.getExternalStorateState();
    }     
}
```

Or if you use **Robolectric** you could call:

```
ShadowEnvironment.setExternalStorageState(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
```

It depends on your setup and needs but I would recommend to invest in **Robolectric** usage

Answer (score 0):

I just worked around wrapping the call to the Environment method in my test helper class so I could mock the status of the SD Card as I wanted depending on a variable I could set as desired in each test case. 
Best solution I think.